# Validar se data informada é menor que a atual javaScript

Tags: javascript

Beleza Pessoal,

Estou tentando valida se uma data informada é menor que a data atual..

```js
var dtVenc = '22/10/2018'; /* Aqui recebe a data String do Json*/

function retornaData(data){
 if(!data){
  return data; 
 }
 split = data.split('/');
 return new Date( split[1] + "/" +split[0]+"/"+split[2] );
}

var dataCurrente = new Date();

 if(retornaData(dtVenc).getTime() < dataCurrente.getTime()){

     alert("A data informada é inferir a data atual");

    }
```

Estou validando se a data informada é menor que a data atual. Até aí, tudo bem! Está validando corretamente, o problema é quando informo o mesmo dia da data atual, ai cai na validação.

E está errado, pois a data informada (igual a atual) não é menor.

Não entendi, muito esse problema de data com JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

segue resposta:

```js
 var dtVenc = '23/10/2018'; /* Aqui recebe a data String do Json*/

    function retornaData(data) {
        if (!data) {
            return data;
        }
        split = data.split('/');
        return new Date(split[1] + "/" + split[0] + "/" + split[2]);
    }

    var dataCurrente = new Date();

    if (retornaData(dtVenc).getDate() < dataCurrente.getDate()) {
        console.log("A data informada é inferir a data atual");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Executando o código abaixo você vai entender o porque quando informa o mesmo dia da data atual cai na validação.

```js
var dtVenc = '22/10/2018'; /* Aqui recebe a data String do Json*/

function retornaData(data){
 if(!data){
  return data; 
 }
 split = data.split('/');
 return new Date( split[1] + "/" +split[0]+"/"+split[2] );
}

var dataCurrente = new Date();

 if(retornaData(dtVenc).getTime() < dataCurrente.getTime()){

    console.log("A data informada é inferir a data atual");

  }
  
  console.log(retornaData(dtVenc).getTime()); //1540177200000
  
  console.log(dataCurrente.getTime());
    
    var jsTimestamp = new Date(1540177200000);
    
    console.log(jsTimestamp);
```

Quando você informa a data somente com dia, mês e ano `'22/10/2018'` o JavaScript assume a data como sendo `"2018-10-22T03:00:00.000Z"`, ou seja, zero hora do dia informado, portanto a expressão `retornaData(dtVenc).getTime()` vai retornar sempre o valor `1540177200000`. Por sua vez, a data de hoje da expressão `dataCurrente.getTime()` será sempre crescente, e obviamente sempre maior que o valor `1540177200000`, a cada segundo que você executar o código acima.

> Para que funcione de forma correta você deveria colocar um horário na data de vencimento `return new Date( split[1] + "/" +split[0]+"/"+split[2] + " 23:59:59");`, veja:

```js
var dtVenc = '22/10/2018'; /* Aqui recebe a data String do Json*/

function retornaData(data){
 if(!data){
  return data; 
 }
 split = data.split('/');
 return new Date( split[1] + "/" +split[0]+"/"+split[2] + " 23:59:59");
}

var dataCurrente = new Date();

 if(retornaData(dtVenc).getTime() < dataCurrente.getTime()){

    console.log("A data informada é inferir a data atual");

  }else{

       console.log("A data ainda não venceu");

  }

console.log(retornaData(dtVenc).getTime());
console.log(dataCurrente.getTime());
```